# Ephesoft Community Edition 4.0.2.0 on ubunutu 14.04 and get past the tesseract issue?

Tags: ephesoft

Has anyone been able to install Ephesoft Community Edition 4.0.2.0 on ubunutu 14.04 and get past the tesseract issue? It can not find the proper files to work properly If so, please provide feedback.

Thank you, Matt

Comment: I did. Are you stuck in the installation process or the software is not working properly once installed? I suggest you to put some more specific information about the issue in order to elucidate if I could help.

Comment: Hello! I have it installed (Ephesoft community edition 4.0.2.0) on Ubunitu 14.04 on Google cloud service 4 core 16gb ram. Everything works except key value extraction does not OCR. In dcma-all.log shows "base path not configured" I know I'm probably missing something simple but I am stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not remember what did I configure in my system but I do realize I had to set or modify some line in the configuration files located at `/opt/Ephesoft/Application/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/` (maybe you installed Ephesoft in other dir --not `/opt/`), for instance: `.../dcma-batches/dcma-batch.properties` . The [ephesoft wiki](http://wiki.ephesoft.com/) was also helpful in some cases.